# Alternate way for port map in process?

Tags: vhdl

As far as my understanding in vhdl, it is not possible to have port mappings to components within a process. and i was curious whether there is an alternative way to approach a conditional scenario.

here's an example of my calculator vhdl code that I am currently working on:

```
    library ieee;
    use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
    use ieee.numeric_std.all;


-- OP CODE TABLE --
-- 00   :   LOAD --
-- 01   :   ADD/SUB  --
-- 10   :   Print--
-- 11   :   BEQ  --

-- li - RS Values --
-- 00 : R0 --
-- 01 : R1 --
-- 10 : R2 --
-- 11 : R3 --


-- //      add     | op, rs, rd, rt       //
-- //      sub     | op, rs, rd, rt       //
-- //      li      | op, rs, immediate    //
-- //      beq     | op, rs, rd, zero     //
-- //      print   | op, rs, zero, one    //


-- Current Problems --

-- need variables?
-- dont know what to do with numInst

entity Calculator is

port (

    Clock       : in std_logic;
    numInst     : in std_logic_vector (7 downto 0);
    --Max Value of PC? 8 bits
    Instruction : in std_logic_vector (7 downto 0);
    --8 bit instruction
    PC          : out std_logic_vector (7 downto 0);
    --8 bit output, used to retrieve next instruction
    PRINTER     : out std_logic_vector (7 downto 0);
    --8 bit output is set to value of register when instruction display is executed
    ENABLE      : in std_logic;
    --when high, instruction execute, when low, hold-no instruction executed
    RESET       : in std_logic
    --on rising edge, reset register value to 0, restart excution of calculator

);

end Calculator;

architecture Behavorial of Calculator is

component ADD is

port (

    A   : in std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);
    B   : in std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);
    Carry   : out std_logic;
    Sum : out std_logic_vector(7 downto 0)

);
end component;


component decode is

port (

    instr   : in std_logic_vector (7 downto 0);
    op  : in std_logic_vector (1 downto 0);
    rs  : in std_logic_vector (1 downto 0);
    rd  : out std_logic_vector (1 downto 0);
    rt  : out std_logic_vector (1 downto 0)

);
end component;

--need variable or signal to store opcode
--maybe need variable to store values identifier of rs, rt, rd
--random comment for something else...idk
--maybe we dont need a separate register vhdl file, make variable?

signal op, rs, rt, rd: std_logic_vector(1 downto 0):=(others=>'0');
signal immediate, AddOut: std_logic_vector(7 downto 0):=(others=>'0');
signal carrybit: std_logic;
--make register signals? R0, R1, R2, R3 
signal R0, R1, R2, R3: std_logic_vector (7 downto 0) := "00000000";

begin


--portmap
decode port map (Instruction, op, rs, rd, rt);

calc: process (Clock, ENABLE, RESET)

-- use variables opcode, rs, rt, rd  to break up Instruction


begin

    if (ENABLE = '0') then

        --nothing, calculator is disabled

    else --ENABLE at 1



        if (rising_edge(RESET)) then

            PC <= "00000000"; -- restart execution
            op <= "00";
            rs <= "00";
            rt <= "00";
            rd <= "00";

            --registers go to 0

        elsif (rising_edge(Clock)) then

            --          


        elsif (Clock = '1') then
            if (op = "00") then
            --maybe can be used to load values into registers

                if(rd(1)='1') then
                    immediate(7 downto 4):='1';
                    immediate(3 downto 2)<= rd;
                    immediate(1 downto 0)<= rt;
                else
                    immediate(7 downto 4):='0';
                    immediate(3 downto 2)<= rd;
                    immediate(1 downto 0)<= rt;         
                end if;


            --PC = PC + 1
            elsif (op = "01") then --add

                if(rs = "00") then
                    if(rt = "00") then
                        addi00: ADD port map(R0,R0,carrybit,AddOut);
                    elsif(rt = "01") then
                        addi01: ADD port map(R0,R1,carrybit,AddOut);
                    elsif(rt = "10") then
                        addi02: ADD port map(R0,R2,carrybit,AddOut);
                    else
                        addi03: ADD port map(R0,R3,carrybit,AddOut);
                    end if;
                elsif(rs = "01") then
                    if(rt = "00") then
                        addi10: ADD port map(R1,R0,carrybit,AddOut);
                    elsif(rt = "01") then
                        addi11: ADD port map(R1,R1,carrybit,AddOut);
                    elsif(rt = "10") then
                        addi12: ADD port map(R1,R2,carrybit,AddOut);
                    else
                        addi13: ADD port map(R1,R3,carrybit,AddOut);
                    end if;
                elsif(rs = "10") then
                    if(rt = "00") then
                        addi20: ADD port map(R2,R0,carrybit,AddOut);
                    elsif(rt = "01") then
                        addi21: ADD port map(R2,R1,carrybit,AddOut);
                    elsif(rt = "10") then
                        addi22: ADD port map(R2,R2,carrybit,AddOut);
                    else
                        addi23: ADD port map(R2,R3,carrybit,AddOut);
                    end if; 
                else
                    if(rt = "00") then
                        addi30: ADD port map(R3,R0,carrybit,AddOut);
                    elsif(rt = "01") then
                        addi31: ADD port map(R3,R1,carrybit,AddOut);
                    elsif(rt = "10") then
                        addi32: ADD port map(R3,R2,carrybit,AddOut);
                    else
                        addi33: ADD port map(R3,R3,carrybit,AddOut);
                    end if;
                end if;
                --use component of adder vhdl file?
                --PC = PC + 1 ?


                --use adder (subtractor) component
                --PC = PC + 1 ?

            elsif (op = "10") then 

            -- need rs, rt, rd, variable?

                    if (rs = "00") then

                        PRINTER <= R0;
                        --insert print code here
                        --PC = PC + 1 -- to continue to next instruction

                    elsif (rs = "01") then

                        PRINTER <= R1;
                        --insert print code here
                        --PC = PC + 1 -- to continue to next instruction

                    elsif (rs = "10") then

                        PRINTER <= R2;
                        --insert print code here
                        --PC = PC + 1 -- to continue to next instruction
                    else  --(rs = "11") then

                        PRINTER <= R3;
                        --insert print code here
                        --PC = PC + 1 -- to continue to next instruction    

                    end if;


            elsif (op = "11") then --beq

                --if (register1 != register2) then

                        --PC <= PC + 1;

                --else

                        --PC <= PC + 2;

                --end if;

            end if;

        end if;

        elsif (falling_edge(Clock)) then

            if (op = "00") then

                if (rs = "00") then

                    R0 <= immediate;

                elsif (rs = "01") then

                    R1 <= immediate;

                elsif (rs = "10") then

                    R2 <= immediate;

                else --rs = "11"

                    R3 <= immediate;

                end if;

            elsif (op = "01") then

                if (rd = "00") then

                    R0 <= AddOut;--output of adder;

                elsif (rd = "01") then

                    R1 <= AddOut;--output of adder;

                elsif (rd = "10") then

                    R2 <= AddOut;--output of adder;

                else --rd = 11

                    R3 <= Addout;--output of adder;

                end if;

            end if;

        end if;

    end if;

end process calc;

end architecture Behavorial;
```

the main problem that i can't really wrap my mind around is how to use my adder component under certain circumstances (the if/else conditions).

Comment: Consider that you can't make hardware magically appear and disappear at will... FPGAs are cool but not THAT cool ... so think along the lines of always having the adder present, but conditionally using or ignoring its output.

Comment: @BrianDrummond Well, unless you want to get into partial reconfiguration. ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As @BrianDrummond says, you can't make hardware magically appear and disappear at will. You cannot decide whether a lump of hardware exists and doesn't exist based on some inputs to the hardware. So, instead, you need to instantiate the hardware once and then control what is being input to it:

```
signal L, R : std_logic_vector (7 downto 0);

-- snip

addi: ADD port map(L,R,carrybit,AddOut);   -- here is the ADD instance

calc: process (Clock, ENABLE, RESET)

-- snip

        --PC = PC + 1
        elsif (op = "01") then --add

            if(rs = "00") then
                if(rt = "00") then
                    L <= R0; R <= R0;
                elsif(rt = "01") then
                    L <= R0; R <= R1;
                elsif(rt = "10") then
                    L <= R0; R <= R2;
                else
                    L <= R0; R <= R3;
                end if;
            elsif(rs = "01") then
                if(rt = "00") then
                    L <= R0; R <= R0;
                elsif(rt = "01") then
                    L <= R1; R <= R1;
                elsif(rt = "10") then
                    L <= R1 R <= R2;
                else
                    L <= R1; R <= R3;
                end if;
            elsif(rs = "10") then
                if(rt = "00") then
                    L <= R2; R <= R0;
                elsif(rt = "01") then
                    L <= R2; R <= R1;
                elsif(rt = "10") then
                    L <= R2; R <= R2;
                else
                    L <= R3; R <= R3;
                end if; 
            else
                if(rt = "00") then
                    L <= R3; R <= R0;
                elsif(rt = "01") then
                    L <= R3; R <= R1;
                elsif(rt = "10") then
                    L <= R3; R <= R2;
                else
                    L <= R3; R <= R3;
                end if;
            end if;
            --use component of adder vhdl file?
```

So, you can see I have declared two new signals `L` and `R` and I am using your process to control what is driving them. The `ADD` block will then add some combination of `R0`, `R1`, `R2` and `R3`.

I have answered you question below, but I see many other problems in your code, even though there's quite a lot of it and I only gave it a quick glance. In order they appear, not in order of seriousness:

i) `signal R0, R1, R2, R3: std_logic_vector (7 downto 0) := "00000000";`

Think very carefully why you are initialising these signals. This might work in an FPGA, but (coming from an IC design background) it seems dangerous to rely on initialising signals.

ii) You are missing the instance name (strictly a *label*) for your decoder:

```
decode port map (Instruction, op, rs, rd, rt);
```

It should be something like:

```
deci : decode port map (Instruction, op, rs, rd, rt);
```

iii) You really ought to use named assoication in your port maps. Instead of:

```
deci : decode port map (Instruction, op, rs, rd, rt);
```

do:

```
deci : decode port map (instr => Instruction, op => op, rs => rs, rd = rd, rt => rt);
```

iv) Your process doesn't fit any template for a synthesisable sequential process:

```
calc: process (Clock, ENABLE, RESET)
begin    

    if (ENABLE = '0') then    

    else --ENABLE at 1

        if (rising_edge(RESET)) then

        elsif (rising_edge(Clock)) then

        elsif (Clock = '1') then
```

Here is a template for a sequential process with an asynchronous reset:

```
process(clock, async_reset)  -- nothing else should go in the sensitivity list
begin
    -- never put anything here
    if async_reset ='1' then  -- or '0' for an active low reset
        -- set/reset the flip-flops here
        -- ie drive the signals to their initial values
    elsif rising_edge(clock) then  -- or falling_edge(clock)
        -- put the synchronous stuff here
        -- ie the stuff that happens on the rising or falling edge of the clock
    end if;
     -- never put anything here
end process;
```

So, `ENABLE` should not be in your sensitivity list; the first line of your process should be:

```
calc: process (Clock, RESET)
```

You should test the `ENABLE` signal after the test for `rising_edge(Clock)`:

```
        elsif (rising_edge(Clock)) then
           if (ENABLE = '0') then
```

You should test the absolute value of reset, not look for a rising edge. And you don't need all those parentheses. ie Not this:

```
    if (rising_edge(RESET)) then
```

this:

```
    if RESET = '1' then
```

This line is redundant:

```
elsif (Clock = '1') then
```

v) You *should not* be testing both edges of the clock. This is not synchronous design. You *cannot* test both edges in a single process. That is not even synthesisable. This needs to go:

```
    elsif (falling_edge(Clock)) then
```

vi) I am concerned that you are driving `R0` to `R3` earlier in the process and then using their values later. It is difficult to see your design intent exactly, but I suspect this will not work:

In VHDL *signals* are not updated until a process *suspends*. If you try to use a signal assigned earlier in a process, you will get the previously assigned value.

**General**

I suggest you break your design into many smaller processes. Have a clear idea for each what kind of hardware you expect for each. Have each perform a specific function, eg multiplexing the inputs to the `ADD block`. For example, consider:

- Is the process sequential or combinational logic?
- is the reset asynchronous or synchronous?
- What are the inputs?
- What are the outputs?

And then pick the appropriate template. I have given one for a sequential process with an asynchronous reset. Here is one for a sequential process without an asynchronous reset:

```
process(clock)  -- nothing else should go in the sensitivity list
begin
    -- never put anything here
    if rising_edge(clock) then    -- or falling_edge(clock)
        -- put the synchronous stuff here
        -- ie the stuff that happens on the rising or falling edge of the clock
    end if;
     -- never put anything here
end process;
```

Comment: Thank you for your feedback. I will definitely try this out. I'm not too comfortable with vhdl as of now, and as you glimpsed through my code, it's more formatted to C/C++ language (because I'm more familiar with that language) rather than actual vhdl  (i know that they are completely different languages).

Comment: @Jon Absolutely fundamentally different. C/C++ are _software languages_; VHDL is a _hardware description language_; you are describing hardware not writing software.