# how can i select from some options with code not in a process in vhdl?

Tags: vhdl, simulation, vivado

i started self learning vhdl language a few weeks ago and i'm very beginner; i have some difficulty in code.

```
begin

    SL: sub_layer port map(
        data_in => data_key_added,
        data_out => data_substituted
    );
```

i need to execute the code above only when the number of rounds is even but don't execute it when the number is odd (in order to reduce power) i want to execute something that have less power instead like

```
xo: XOR_layer port map(
        data_in => xo,
        data_out => data
);
```

#

```
process(clk) 
 if rising_edge(clk) then
 case  to_integer(unsigned(round_counter) mod 2)is
         when 0 =>  -- execute (sub_layer) only 
         when others =>  --  execute (XoR_layer) only

  end case;
```

so how can i select from port maps options?

Comment: You don't execute one or the other. You instantiate both, they always execute. Then you select the output you require.

Comment: my main goal is to execute some instruction when it's even and other instruction that are different when it's odd , ex: if even (plain text+key update --> perm_layer()-->sub_layer()) if its odd (plain +key-->xor_layer()))...if i execute both  them this will not reduce the power

Comment: So ... you want VHDL code that makes hardware appear and disappear according to some signal value? ... in current silicon technology, good luck with that.

Comment: yes, but i don't know how to do it ,if you have any idea i will grateful to you

Comment: I can only refer you to my first comment.

Comment: Don't think in terms of "execute instruction" but more in terms of hardware. You don't write software, you design hardware.

Comment: Consider taking the [Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and checking out the help [Asking](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking). The intent is that successful questions with accepted answers are a [search resource](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bvhdl%5D+port+map+process) (Try [Alternate way for port map in process?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37039086/alternate-way-for-port-map-in-process), your question is a duplicate). This leads to asking and answering guidelines.

Comment: VHDL does not compile to an executable, like basic/c/fortran/etc. It does not have a program counter. You describe hardware with it.

Answer (score 0):

Imagine two chips on a PCB: you can't magically make them appear and disappear, they are always there. What you can do is select between the outputs of one or the other. As commenters has said, when you write VHDL you are designing hardware, not writing software. You cannot choose whether you execute hardware or not, hardware always exists for all time. If you want to select between one bit of hardware and another, as Brian says, you have to choose between the outputs of each.

Now selecting between the outputs of two blocks of hardware will not save you any power (which you say you want to do). If you want to save power you need to turn off those blocks some how. The easy way is to stop clocking the block you wish not to use; the hard way is to actually turn off the power. When I say "easy", I mean "hard, dangerous and fraught with difficulty"; when I say "hard", I mean "even harder". You say that you only started self-learning VHDL a few weeks ago. What you are asking about is not a VHDL language issue, but a more fundamental digital design issue. And it is a difficult issue.

Comment: See [Alternate way for port map in process?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37039086/alternate-way-for-port-map-in-process), which you answered.