# executing mux or decode in register

Tags: vhdl, decoder, mux

**Mux** alone works , **Decoder** alone works

Now I want to choose which one to use based on my write_ena in code.

I tried making process and if-else but didn't work and errors in it

**My code:**

```
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
-- Company: 
-- Engineer: 
-- 
-- Create Date:    16:49:06 04/01/2018 
-- Design Name: 
-- Module Name:    RegisterFile - Behavioral 
-- Project Name: 
-- Target Devices: 
-- Tool versions: 
-- Description: 
--
-- Dependencies: 
--
-- Revision: 
-- Revision 0.01 - File Created
-- Additional Comments: 
--
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
use ieee.std_LOGIC_arith.all;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
use ieee.std_logic_unsigned.all;
USE WORK.mux_pkg.ALL;
USE WORK.decoder_pkg.all;
-- Uncomment the following library declaration if using
-- arithmetic functions with Signed or Unsigned values
--use IEEE.NUMERIC_STD.ALL;

-- Uncomment the following library declaration if instantiating
-- any Xilinx primitives in this code.
--library UNISIM;
--use UNISIM.VComponents.all;

entity RegisterFile is    
 Port ( read_sel1 : in  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (4 downto 0);     
 read_sel2 : in  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (4 downto 0);          
 write_sel : in  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (4 downto 0);          
 write_ena : in  STD_LOGIC;     
 clk : in STD_LOGIC;        
 write_data : in  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (31 downto 0);       
 data1 : out  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (31 downto 0);    
 data2 : out  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (31 downto 0)
 );
 end RegisterFile;


architecture Behavioral of RegisterFile is


begin

process (write_ena)

variable r0,r1,r2,r3,r4,r5,r6,r7,r8,r9,r10,r11,r12,r13,r14,r15,r16,r17,
r18,r19,r20,r21,r22,r23,r24,r25,r26,r27,r28,r29,r30,r31: STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (31 downto 0);

variable temp : STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (31 downto 0);

begin

if (write_ena = '1') then

D1: decoder PORT MAP (write_sel,temp);


elsif (write_ena = '0') then
M1: mux PORT MAP (r0,r1,r2,r3,r4,r5,r6,r7,r8,r9,r10,r11,r12,r13,r14,r15,r16,r17,
r18,r19,r20,r21,r22,r23,r24,r25,r26,r27,r28,r29,r30,r31,read_sel1,data1);

M2: mux PORT MAP (r0,r1,r2,r3,r4,r5,r6,r7,r8,r9,r10,r11,r12,r13,r14,r15,r16,r17,
r18,r19,r20,r21,r22,r23,r24,r25,r26,r27,r28,r29,r30,r31,read_sel2,data2);

end if;
end process;
end Behavioral;
```

I have package for mux and package for decoder

**Errors i get:**

> ERROR:HDLCompiler:806 -Line 66: Syntax error near "PORT"
>
> ERROR:HDLCompiler:806 -Line 70: Syntax error near "PORT"
>
> ERROR:HDLCompiler:806  -Line 71: Syntax error near ";"

and so on till the end of my process

**QUESTION:**

I understand that I cannot initiate port inside process so my question is:
How to choose just one to work (either mux or decoder) inside my architecture

Comment: A component instantiation is a concurrent statement which cannot occur in the a place suitable for a sequential statement (such as in an if statement in a process). See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37039086/alternate-way-for-port-map-in-process. You've also tried to use actuals in a port map that are variables.

Comment: @user1155120 is there a way to avoid it because i want to execute either mux or decoder (only one) base on my write_ena ?

Comment: A multiplexer can be expressed in an if statement, a case statement a selected or conditional signal assignment statement, .... With -2008 support the last two can be sequential statements as well as concurrent statements. A decoder can easily be expressed in a subprogram call as a sequential statement or expression.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [port map in structural VHDL code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21164449/port-map-in-structural-vhdl-code)

Comment: @user1155120 i'm sorry im beginner so i don't fully understand you but if you can show me a code how to solve this problem ?

Comment: I have strong feeling, that you think you are writing program. You are wrong - you are designing hardware. What you are trying to do is connecting two kind of resistors in one place, one of them when some signal is low, and another, when signal is high. You can't do that, you must have both of them, and use mux or something.

Comment: Look up the `generate` statement. However, you cannot change component instantiation **during compilation/elaboration/simulation**. VHDL describes wires, and wires are fixed.

Comment: can't i use mux to choose either of them somehow?

Comment: Yes, you can use mux, but you have to instantiate them both, and then connect them to this mux.

Comment: [You don't have to get lost in the detail with your register file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sicHB.jpg)